# Liquibase databasechangelog table stores relative path if run spring boot and let liquibase do the migration automatically

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I know that liquibase will create a databasechangelog to check if one change set has been applied. But if i let the app to run it automatically, the FILENAME column will store the relative path of the changelog file. But if I run mvn liquibase:status, it said my change set had not been applied, the cause is that in liquibase.properties file I defined the path of the changelog as absolute path (i.e changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/db-changeLog-master.xml) while for spring boot app automatic migration the path was defined as relative path (spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db-changeLog-master.xml) in application.properties file and "db/changelog/db-changeLog-master.xml" was stored in the database. If you do it manually (by running mvn liquibase:update), "src/main/resources/db/changelog/db-changeLog-master.xml" would be stored instead.

How could I solve this problem? Since I wanna have control over the migration (i.e. do the migration manually) or check the status of migration in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

after I changed the property: changeLogFile=/db/changelog/db-changeLog-master.xml, in liquibase.properties, mvn command works as expected: now liquibase consider the path of my changelog to be "db/changelog/db-changeLog-master.xml"